# Kernel Management

Tags: resource-management, kernel

I would like to run a computation in one NoteBook that will take 2 hours.

Could I assign this Notebook a specific Kernel so I can run computation in other Notebooks ?

Comment: well, have you tried looking at the menus, eg `Evaluation`->`Kernel configuration options`?

Comment: Why don't you start up an additional front end as well?  If your front end crashes or locks up, it'll take the running kernel with it.  It's better to separate the front ends too when you are running a long calculation while working on something else.

Comment: Depending on the operating system, it might not be straightforward to start a separate front end. For example, OSX actively discourages multiple running instances of an application. The only way I know around this is to manually run the executable inside the application bundle.

Comment: @acl, I did. I don`t understand how it works so I did not want to just "try".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can select which kernel is used by your notebook from the menu item Evaluation -> Notebook's Kernel. By default you will probably only have one kernel called Local available. If your Mathematica license allows for it (typically licenses allow for two simultaneous kernels on a machine), you can add new kernels by selecting the Evaluation -> Kernel Configuration Options... menu item. Select "New" to add a new Kernel, give the kernel any name you want and accept the default options. This new kernel will now be selectable from the Evaluation -> Notebooks Kernel menu.